# how to resolve connection refuse in flutter

Tags: flutter, request, get

I am trying to retrieve some information along with images from my backend in my flutter app. The backend is with spring boot and I am getting this error Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 56766. The backend is hosted locally.
This error is mainly from the image because if I remove the image from my DataModel class, other information is returned successfully without the error.

```
        import 'dart:convert';
        
        import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
        import 'package:vacation_tour_app/model/data_model.dart';
        
        class DataServices{
          String baseUrl = 'http://192.168.43.5:8080/';
          Future<List<DataModel>>getInfo() async {
            var apiUrl = 'tourist/getAll';
            http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl+apiUrl));
        
            try{
              if(res.statusCode==200){
                List<dynamic> list = json.decode(res.body);
                return list.map((e) => DataModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
              }else{
                return <DataModel>[];
              }
            }catch(e){
              print(e);
              return <DataModel>[];
            }
          }
        }
        
        
        class DataModel{
           String name;
           String description;
           String image;
           int price;
           int people;
           int stars;
           String location;
           DataModel({
             required this.price,
             required this.name,
             required this.description,
             required this.image,
             required this.location,
             required this.people,
             required this.stars
        });
           factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json){
             return DataModel(
             price: json["price"],
             name: json["name"],
           description: json["description"],
           image: json["image"],
           location: json["location"],
           people: json["people"],
           stars: json["stars"]);
           }
        }
    error from the logcat
    
    ======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
    The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
    Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 56884
    
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:35)
    #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1817:26)
    #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
    #3      Socket._startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2038:22)
    #4      Socket.startConnect (dart:io/socket.dart:792:21)
    #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2440:18)
    #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2834:12)
    #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2839:12)
    #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2698:12)
    #9      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2575:48)
    #10     NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:87:59)
    #11     NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
    #12     ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
    #13     ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:380:22)
    #14     ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:83)
    #15     ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
    #16     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:26)
    #17     SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:35)
    #18     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:461:11)
    #22     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:453:16)
    #23     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:5)
    #24     DecorationImagePainter.paint (package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart:316:55)
    #25     _BoxDecorationPainter._paintBackgroundImage (package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart:465:20)
    #26     _BoxDecorationPainter.paint (package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart:483:5)
    #27     RenderDecoratedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2150:17)
    #28     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #29     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #31     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #32     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #33     RenderShiftedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:79:15)
    #34     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #35     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #37     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #38     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #40     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #41     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #43     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #44     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #45     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #46     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #47     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #49     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #50     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #51     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:647:17)
    #52     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #53     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #54     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:274:15)
    #55     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #56     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #57     RenderViewportBase._paintContents (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:660:17)
    #58     PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:387:12)
    #59     PaintingContext.pushClipRect (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:443:7)
    #60     RenderViewportBase.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:635:38)
    #61     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #62     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #63     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #64     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #65     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #66     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #67     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #68     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #70     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #71     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #72     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #73     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #74     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #75     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #76     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #77     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #79     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #80     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #82     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #83     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #85     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #86     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #87     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #88     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #89     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #90     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #91     RenderCustomPaint.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:608:11)
    #92     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #93     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #95     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #96     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #97     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #98     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #99     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #100    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #101    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #102    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #103    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #104    PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #105    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #107    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #108    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #109    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:647:17)
    #110    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #111    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #112    RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:274:15)
    #113    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #114    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #115    RenderViewportBase._paintContents (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:660:17)
    #116    PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:387:12)
    #117    PaintingContext.pushClipRect (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:443:7)
    #118    RenderViewportBase.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:635:38)
    #119    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #120    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #121    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #122    PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #123    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #124    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #125    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #126    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #127    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #128    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #129    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #130    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #131    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #132    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #133    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #134    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #135    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #136    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #137    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #138    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #139    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #140    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #141    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #142    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #143    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #144    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #145    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #146    PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #147    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #148    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #149    RenderCustomPaint.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:608:11)
    #150    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #151    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #152    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #153    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #154    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #155    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #156    PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:198:7)
    #157    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:185:7)
    #158    RenderShiftedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:79:15)
    #159    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #160    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #161    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #162    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #163    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #164    RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2847:15)
    #165    RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1078:7)
    #166    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #167    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #168    RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2847:15)
    #169    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:408:5)
    #170    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #171    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #172    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #173    _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:555:11)
    #174    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #175    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #176    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #177    PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:387:12)
    #178    RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1929:15)
    #179    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #180    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #181    RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2847:15)
    #182    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:408:5)
    #183    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #184    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #185    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #186    _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:555:11)
    #187    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #188    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #189    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #190    PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:387:12)
    #191    RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1929:15)
    #192    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #193    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #194    RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2847:15)
    #195    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:408:5)
    #196    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #197    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #198    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #199    _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:555:11)
    #200    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #201    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #202    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #203    PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:387:12)
    #204    RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1929:15)
    #205    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #206    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #207    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #208    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #209    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:13)
    #210    RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
    #211    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2449:7)
    #212    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
    #213    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
    #214    PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:995:29)
    #215    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:499:19)
    #216    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
    #217    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
    #218    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
    #219    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
    #220    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
    #224    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
    #225    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
    #226    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
    (elided 6 frames from dart:async)
    Image provider: NetworkImage("http://localhost:8080/download/44021c90-7b33-4262-aa0c-c29cf7fc69b1", scale: 1.0)
    Image key: NetworkImage("http://localhost:8080/download/44021c90-7b33-4262-aa0c-c29cf7fc69b1", scale: 1.0)
    ====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your trouble lies entirely on your connection, have you tried changing the IP address on your code and/or checking if you're using some kind of firewall, proxy, VPN on your computer that may refuse connections?
Would be great if you try those requests on a different environment such as Postman using the same IP address on your Flutter code.
PS: It could be also something as trivial as changing your `http` scheme to `https`.

Comment: I have tested the IP address on Postman and it's working perfectly @Alain C. Jimenez. I don't know why it's not working on the App

Comment: Please @Alain C. Jimenez I have updated the question with the full logcat message. The issue is mainly from my image and not from my api. please the updated question for me

Comment: In your question you're saying: `Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 56766`, in the code I'm seeing: `String baseUrl = 'http://192.168.43.5:8080/';` and in the log you're getting: `address = localhost, port = 56884`, so clearly there's something fussy about the Ip address you're using and/or the port listening, try using Postman or the browser itself to get the resources and have a better understanding.